# Redirect to page user was trying to get to after logging in

Tags: php, redirect

Been reading a bit to find the answer with not too much luck.

I have a site where members can browse the site anonymously but some pages are restricted. I have the members redirected to a login page once they click a link that needs them to be logged in to view.

The problem I'm facing is I don't know how to redirect the member to the page they were trying to get to once logged in.

They tried to to get to /profile.phtml , it sent them to /login.phtml , now when they log in, I want them to be sent to /profile.phtml because that's where they clicked to get to. If they clicked /album.phtml, I want them to be sent to /album.phtml after login.

Can anyone help? Do I somehow store the URL in a session?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Store the URL in the querystring. I don't use PHP so I cant give you the code but this is how ASP.Net does it. You are returned to the login page with a URL like this: login.aspx?returnurl=orginalpage.aspx. Then when they log in read the querystring parameter and redirect to the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just before making the `header("Location:")` call to redirect, store the page they're currently on in `$_SESSION['redirect_to']`.  Upon successful login, make another `header()` call to redirect back to the original page and unset the session variable so it doesn't get accidentally reused anywhere.

```
$_SESSION['redirect_to'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: http://example.com/login.php");
exit();

// On successful login
$redirect = $_SESSION['redirect_to'];
// unset the session var
unset($_SESSION['redirect_to']);
header("Location: http://example.com/$redirect");
exit();
```

Comment: I think thats an unnecessary amount of work and session storage for something that is supported by the browser itself.

Comment: Worked like a charm, beautiful! Thank you. If only I could have thought of this... such a simple concept. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You could very well use a session variable like other people are suggesting. However, I'd rather rely on HTTP_REFFERER. The drawback here is not every browser sends a referrer, but most major browsers do. It's a part of the HTTP standard and I think it's good enough. Stick this in your login script.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); }
```

Comment: `HTTP_REFERRER` is often empty, as you said - particularly when using HTTPS.  Many browsers will _never_ send the referrer over https.

Comment: @Michael This only occurs if the referrer and the new location are not secure. If the session is HTTPS across the board, you will see referrer populated.