# How to transfer a user to the last page they were on prior logging out?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a website that uses session to allow users to safely access my website. I also have an idle time out session (if the use is idle for 20 minutes they get a pop up message to see if they are still on the site if not it will destroy their session and direct them to the log in page. What I want to do it to take them back to where they were prior the log out.

For example, assume I am on a page called articles.php?id=100 reading a long article. Then, the system logs me out because I have been idle for a while. Now, I log in using my username and password. Upon log in, I want to system to direct me back to article.php?id=100 not to index.php. currently, on every log in request the system send the use to index.php.

Second scenario: I send an email with a list to another user (ie. article.php?id=100) but this user is not logged in so the system will automatically direct them to the log in page. In this case I also was to take them to article.php?id=100 not to index.php

**Question**: How can I figure out what url was requested prior the transfer via Header('Location: index.php') so I can transfer the user back to that url. This will have to redirect if the refered site was the same URL.

Comment: There are really way too many answers for this to be considered on-topic for Stack Overflow. Suggestion: do some research on redirects after login, pick a method, and stick with it. If you run into any **specific** roadblocks with your code along the way, those would be the questions you should post here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have following code before the redirect `Header('Location: index.php')` and provide the current url to the login page:

`$currentUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '?' .$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
header('Location: index.php?redirectTo=' . urlencode($currentUrl));`

Then include the `redirectTo` paremeters as a hidden input field in the login form:

`<input type="hidden" name="redirectTo" value="<?php echo $_GET['redirectTo']"?>" />`

And then you can use it after the login to redirect to the page in question:

`//after login code
header('Location: '. $_REQUEST['redirectTo']);
exit();//for good measure`

Adjust this code according to the framework that you use, I assume vanilla php here....

Comment: Thank you. You gave me the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this but on every page change you could store the currently visited uri of the user in a simple key:value datastore, as example SQLite, memcached, or even as a cookie. After the logout you check that key and redirect the user to that site.